# Assigning a type to a react hook object in ts on invocation

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am calling this hook:

```
  const count = useDocsCount({
    collectionRef: 'notifications',
    filter: {
      filterKey: 'seen',
      operator: '==',
      filterValue: false
    } 
  })
```

Where filter object has 3 fields. I am trying to make sure that the filterKey corresponds to a field from the `INotification` interface, defined below:

```
export interface INotification  {
    dateCreated: Timestamp,
    seen: boolean,
    notificationID: string,
    text: string,
    title: string,
    type: TNotificationType
}
```

I want TS to give an error if the filterKey does not correspond to one of the fields of this interface.
Note, I do not want to do this directly in the hook since other components use this hook and the interface that I want to base the filterKey off of will change in those other components.
As a bonus, if possible, if filterKey is seen, then is it possible to make sure that filterValue is of the corresponding type of seen which comes from `INotification` (boolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach creates a parameter to suit the useDocsCount hook without changing the hook signature.

```js
export interface INotification {
  dateCreated: Date;
  seen: boolean;
  notificationID: string;
  text: string;
  title: string;
  type: "whatever";
}

interface NotificationParam<FieldName extends keyof INotification> {
  collectionRef: "notifications";
  filter: {
    filterKey: FieldName;
    operator: "==";
    filterValue: INotification[FieldName];
  };
}

function createParam<FieldName extends keyof INotification>(
  param: NotificationParam<FieldName>
) {
  return param;
}

const param = createParam({
  collectionRef: "notifications",
  filter: {
    filterKey: "seen",
    operator: "==",
    filterValue: true,
  },
});
```